# What is the best / common practice to include a function that is used from several scripts?

Tags: bash

I currently did this by sourcing a functions file including all my functions into the several scripts that use it:

```
source ./functions.sh
```

One disadvantage I noticed is that the line number bash prints for syntax errors is not any more the one of the original script.

Comment: Can you add the version of `bash` on which you find this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using it is reasonable.
I cannot reproduce your problem with the *bash shell* I could work on (GNU bash, version 4.1.2 and GNU bash, version 4.3.11). See it below:

---

Test script `go.sh`. You can run it with `./go.sh` after you make it executable with `chmod u+x go.sh` as well as `/bin/bash go.sh`

```
echo  "   ### Here we start ###"  Script line 1
source my_sourced_file
echo Script line 3
casfsda    # this is the line 4 of script
echo Script line 5
f  "Script line #6 using the function from sourced file"
echo "   ### Here we finish ###" Script line 7
```

File with functions that you have to put in the current directory named `my_sourced_file`:

```
echo Hello word this is the 1 line of my_sourced_file
f(){ echo Hello $1 ;}
f "Gustave line number 3 of  my_sourced_file"
echo linea 4 my_sourced_file
```

Output (in **black** the error)

> ### Here we start ### Script line 1
>   Hello word this is the 1 line of my_sourced_file
>   Hello Gustave line number 3 of my_sourced_file
>   linea 4 my_sourced_file
>   Script line 3
>   **./go.sh: line 4: casfsda: command not found**
>   Script line 5
>   Hello Script line #6 using the function from sourced file
>      ### Here we finish ### Script line 7

- Tested on GNU bash, version 4.3.11
- and on old GNU bash, version 4.1.2